# Dialog with LongListSelector\ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone

I am developing Windows Phone app and i want to add something like Dialog(Android) that popup and show a `ListBox` \ `LongListSelector` in this Dialog.

I use something called `InputPrompt` to show dialog with TextBox. There is something like this that show `ListBox` \ `LongListSelector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CustomMessageBox`, available through the [WPToolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/).

You're looking to create something like this to solve your problem:

```
ListPicker picker = new ListPicker()
{
    Header = "SOME HEADER",
    ItemsSource = YourViewModel.SomeCollectionWithItems,
    Margin = new Thickness(12, 42, 24, 18)
};

CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
{
    Caption = "This is a message box",
    Message = "Select one of the items from the list.",
    Content = picker,
    LeftButtonContent = "ok",
    RightButtonContent = "cancel"
};
```

Obviously, the content property can be set to a wide variety of UI controls, so feel free to switch around. The provided [out-of-the-box samples](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest) covers possible implementations.